# Is there a procedure to convert m-file-function to C(or MEX) S-function?

Tags: matlab, simulink, symbolic-computation, s-function

I have a simple function written as MATLAB code. For example:

```
function s = sum_inputs(a,b)

s = a+b;
```

This function derives from `matlabFunction` command application using a symbolic expression.
I could like to convert it to S-Function for speed-up performance, for example to a C S-function, MEX S-Function, etc instead of using it in MATLAB S-function block or Interpreted MATLAB block. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a C or MEX S-Function for something as simple as that. Use a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block instead. It uses code generation so is much faster than an [interpreted MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html) block.